# Natural phrase for "a dish that doesn't have a lot of salt" and "a dish that doesn't have a lot of sugar"

Tags: word-usage

My friend made a dish and asked me to taste it. I said:

> ***It's okay but it has less salt***.(like a bit tasteless , it's salty but not as salty as it should be )

And for cake if it doesn't have sugar:

> ***It's okay but it has less sugar*** .(it's sweet but not as sweet as it should be.)

Answer (score 1):

[Bland](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bland) -lacking strong flavor

Though this word does not particularly indicate lack of salt.

Comment: But what if I want to specify "sugar" or "salt" in my sentence?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know any words that specifically refer to insufficiency of salt or sugar. Hope you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The best term to fit your current sentence structure is **"too little"**, in place of "less".

> It's okay but it has **too little** salt.
>
> It's okay but it has **too little** sugar.

Other structures are possible, and may be more likely for native speakers ("too little" sounds a bit formal to me):

> It's okay but it **needs more** salt/sugar.
>
> It's okay but it **doesn't have enough** salt/sugar.

Comment: Can it be :. It's okay but it doesn't have enough sugar.(can sugar be used this way too.?) And : It's okay but it needs more salt( in place of sugar)

Comment: Please help me out. My question is whether the sentences you used that would be used, can "salt" be used with:                                       
 It needs more salt.(you used this with sugar.)      And:                                       It doesn't have enough sugar.(you used it with "salt" in your sentence.)

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish: Yes, those are both fine. I will edit my post to include all combinations.